# React how to call a method from store and from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make page pagintation in my model . I've used @material-ui `TablePagination` . The thing is, I'm using a web service to load my data and I don't want to store all the data inside the page, so I'm using the API paging offered (send parameters to the url for the correct page) .

Now to my code :

```
    <TablePagination
          component="div"
          count={props.totalTableRows}
          rowsPerPage={props.rowsPerPage}
          page={props.brokersListPage}
          onChangePage={props.setBrokersListPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions = {[props.rowsPerPage]}
        />
```

And the `setBrokersListPage` :

```
export const setBrokersListPage = (event, page) => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
          type: actionNames.SET_BROKERSLIST_PAGE,
          page 
        })
        getBrokers(page)
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work . I need the dispatch action to refresh the state of the page , and I need the `getBrokers` to call the web service once again with the correct info . But all this does is update the page state without updating the data.

If I use this :

```
export const setBrokersListPage = (event, page) => {
    return getBrokers(page)
  }
```

Then the page refreshes , but then the state doesn'
tget refreshed .

How can I achieve both ?

Comment: what does `getBrokers` do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an API call first, then pass this data to store, connected component will update afterwards. In your code i suppose you don't use the actual data from web service.

Here is simplified example:

```
Promise.resolve()
  .then((page) => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: LOADING_BROKERS
    });
    return Api.getbrokers(page);
    //get brokers here
  })
  .then(() => {
    store.dispatch({
      type: LOADED_DATA_BROKERS,
      pageinfo // or whatever
    });
  })
```

Comment: You need to do some action on URL change(page change). `onChangePage={props.setBrokersListPage}` after page will be changed you will make a web service call and dispatch appropriate action with your data payload. Hope this helps.